# Question about metric for a.s. convergence

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

A remark following a theorem (about real numbers) in Durrett says:

Theorem: Let $y_n$ be a sequence of elements of a topological space. If every subsequence $y_{n(m)}$ has a further subsequence $y_{n(m_k)}$ that converges to $y$, then $y_n\rightarrow y$.

Remark: Since there is a sequence of random variables that converge in probability but not a.s., it follows from the theorem above that a.s. convergence does not come from a metric, or even a topology.

I'm not sure how that follows from the theorem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is somewhat terse, but it suffices to couple the theorem mentioned with the fact that convergence in probability to $X$ implies convergence a.s. of a subsequence also to $X$.

Now take $X_n$ that converges to $X$ in probability but not almost surely. Fix a subsequence. By the result above, there is a subsequence (of this subsequence) that converges almost surely to $X$. By the result you mentioned, if a.s. convergence came from a topology, we should have $X_n \to X$ almost surely, but this isn't the case.

Comment: Ahh I see, can you please elaborate on why the statement "if a.s. convergence came from a topology, we should have $X_n\rightarrow X$ a.s." is true? I guess I don't understand what it means for a convergence to come from a topology. But that explains why convergence in probability comes from a metric. Thanks.

Comment: @manifolded Because what we have in my answer is an argument showing that $X_n$ is such that every subsequence has a further subsequence converging a.s. to $X$. Since the theorem in your post is valid if the sequence lies in a topological space and the convergence is in the sense of said topology, it follows that a.s. convergence can't be a convergence in the sense of any topology.